# How to echo a variable that I don't know is set or not in an easy to read way in PHP

Tags: php, variables, isset

just have a simple question. I think I know the answer but I hope not.

I want to be able to echo out a variable that I don't know whether is set or not. So I want a default variable if it is not set and I don't want to have to check if it is set first.

So here is an example:

I have a $variable that I don't know whether is set or not.

Then

```
echo "This is my number: " . $variable;
```

If $variable is set as 5, I want it to print "This is my number: 5" and if not set, I want it to print "This is my number: 0".

I know I could do something like this:

```
echo "This is my number: " . ($variable? : 0);
```

But then I still get a notice saying $variable is undefined, even though the echo displays correctly.

I could also do something like this

```
if (!isset($variable)) 
{
  $variable = 0);
}
echo "This is my number: " . $variable;
```

But that's too much code if I'm doing this a lot.

Comment: If you're going to use `$variable` for something else after this echo statement, it would be better to check if it's set and set it to a default value once before the echo statement. Otherwise, you'll just have to do this isset checking/default value setting again. (I'm not assuming you don't know this, but it seems worth saying regardless.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) is your new best friend.

```
echo "This is my number: " . ($variable ?? 0);
```

---

The null coalescing operator is available as of PHP 7.0.0.  An alternative, for use in older versions right back to PHP 5.3.0, is to use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and the [`ternary operator`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) `?:`.

```
echo "This is my number: " . (isset($variable) ? $variable : 0);
```

Comment: * Best friend applies only to PHP 7+ :)

Comment: @ishegg Which everyone should be using nowadays.

Comment: @salathe not quite. Ruby is even better 

Comment: I guess this is the answer I am looking for... even though I am not using PHP 7.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
echo "This is my number: " . (isset($variable) ? $variable : 0);
```

Works in PHP 5+